# problem with background-image : url("img/download.jpg") ;

Tags: html, css

when import image in css noting happen but I check (address) and everything on code
for example I write this on my  style :

`* { background-image: url('img/download.jpg') ; background-repeat: no-repeat ; }`

and then add background color but not happen again
my url direction is true and file exist
and no where in my code this work
I use external style code and link it in head and other property work clean(work with vs code)
somebody help me with this

Comment: Try to use it this way `body{
   background-image: url(img/download.jpg);
}` no need to use quotes.

Comment: Have you used your dev tools inspect facility to make sure that that url is correct? Can you also try to put in the full url (e.g. starting http) just to make sure that the image is being served from where you think it is being served. And did you really want every single element to have that background?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it this way  `body {background-image: url(img/download.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat ; }` and no need to use quotes.

```css
body 
{
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnJVo.png?s=256&g=1);
background-repeat: no-repeat ;

}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set `background-size` to show background-image

```css
body 
{
background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnJVo.png?s=256&g=1);
background-size : 100px;
background-repeat: no-repeat ;

}
```